# Confused by (cumulative) distribution function question...

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$P(0<=X<1)$ if $X$ is a random variable having a distribution function:

$F(x)=$ {($0, x<0$), ($1/3, 0<=x<1$), ($2/3, 1<=x<2$), ($1, x>=2)$} (hope that makes sense)

But if $x$ can potentially equal anything above $2$ all the way to infinity then surely the probability that $X=x$ where $x$ is between 0 and 1 is practically 0, so is that the answer?

Also as a side question, what is f(x) equal to in this case? F(x) = integral of f(x) right? But all of F(x) are constants?

Comment: Your statement that $X $ the random variable can equal anything above 2 to infinity is incorrect. The CDF is a function of the upper bound of a random variable. It being 1 at infinity does in no way imply $X $ can be above 2. According to your definition the PDF has compact support (0,2). Thus (0,2) are the random variables infinite range of possibilities.

Comment: The probability that $X$ is between 0 and 1 is $F_X (1^+)-F (0^-)=1/3$. And this turns out to be a PMF not PDF

Comment: If you look further at the CDF  you will realize this is a discrete RV and thus has a PMF not PDF

Answer (score 1):

$x$ cannot be greater than 2, because the cumulative function does not increase, i.e. the probability of x being less than 50000 is the same of being less than 2, so x will not be between 2 and 50000. For your problem, $P(0\leqslant x<1)=\frac{1}{3}$, because 0, 1 and 2 are given probability $\frac{1}{3}$, but only 0 is in $0\leqslant x<1$.

For discrete distributions, the integral is a sum; that's why 0, 1 and 2 are given probability $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

We are given the piecewise cumulative distribution function $$\Pr[X \le x] = F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0 \\ 1/3, & 0 \le x < 1 \\ 2/3, & 1 \le x < 2 \\ 1, & 2 \le x. \end{cases}$$  What the first two cases tell us is that $\Pr[X = 0] = 1/3$, since $$\Pr[X \le 0]$$ corresponds to the choice $x = 0$ in the above function, thus we know $$\Pr[X \le 0] = 1/3.$$  But we also know $$\Pr[X = 0] = \Pr[X \le 0] - \Pr[X < 0] = 1/3 - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^-} \Pr[X \le \epsilon] = 1/3 - 0 = 1/3.$$  So the jump discontinuity of $F_X$ at $x = 0$ indicates that there is a **discrete** probability mass at $x = 0$.  Furthermore, we can observe, for example, $$\Pr[X = 1/2] = \Pr[X \le 1/2] - \Pr[X < 1/2] = 1/3 - 1/3 = 0,$$ which suggests more generally that whenever $F_X$ is constant on some open interval $(a,b)$, the probability that $X \in (a,b)$ is zero.  So here, we are faced with a completely discrete distribution.

This also suggests that $\Pr[X > 2] = 0$, for we can see that $\Pr[X \le 2] = F_X(2) = 1$ from the definition.  So $$\Pr[X > 2] = 1 - \Pr[X \le 2] = 1 - 1 = 0.$$

Answer (score -1):

You have $P(X < 1) = F_X(1-)$ and $P(X \ge 0) = 1 - P(X < 0) = 1 - F_X(0-)$.